# Arbitrary input

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have LibreOffice 4.1.2 on my winbox and I cannot make it accept an arbitrary input.

The minimal test:

1. create a new Calc document;
2. input `KBr`;
3. press Enter.

Then the text turns into `Kbr`. Setting the cell format to Text does not help at all.

The similar question 
[How to prevent OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc from changing what you input (data, numbers,...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835264/how-to-prevent-openoffice-libreoffice-calc-from-changing-what-you-input-data-n) was mainly about importing and didn't help me either.

So, is there a way to insert an arbitrary text piece into a cell - at least my minimal example?

Comment: Thank you for this question, Bowdzone has the answer, Tools → AutoCorrect → Options, and in your case there's a specific TWo CApital correction setting. LibreOffice, listen to me, put all options under Options, not some unknown other place

Answer (score 1):

*Copied from question:*

It has turned out that the options related to autocorrecting the text are located under the separate menu Tools → AutoCorrect

The description: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Deactivating_Automatic_Changes

In my case, I just turned this feature off in Tools → AutoCorrect → Options

Answer (score 0):

It is just the effect of a dumb language corrector trying to avoid typos. Disable all of them and your input will be kept. Tools → Options... → Language settings → Writing aids. I usually disable everything here; but trying you can keep a bare minimum while avoiding case correction.

Comment: Didn't help, though helped me to start searching in the right direction. I've updated the post with the description.

Comment: I haven't checked the version, in fact I have a different version from yours. Though, we are talking about the same stuff.